# Need help with a regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

In my .NET app, I am required to parse text, which can have inline conditions, like this:

> Here is some text. **{{if:** condition **}}** Here is some conditional text. **{{endif}}** Here is more text.

And so I have written the following regular expression to find these conditions:

```
\{\{if\:(?<condition>[^\}]+)\}\}(?<value>.+)\{\{endif\}\}
```

This has worked fine for me, and achieved what I want, until I have had to deal with an input with two conditions:

> **{{if:** condition **}}** content **{{endif}}** some other content **{{if:** condition2 **}}** content2 **{{endif}}**

In this case, my regular expression picks up the entire string, starting with the {{if}} of the first condition, and ending with the {{endif}} of the second condition, making my applciation not work correctly.

How can I rewrite my regular expression to make this work? Or do I have to achieve it without regular expressions?

EDIT: I should have said the content within the conditions can also have double curly brackets to represent other constructs, and so it's not as simple is just ignoring those!

*NOTE: There is also the potential issue of nested conditions, but I don't think I'll have to worry about those!*

Comment: "There is also the potential issue of nested conditions, but I don't think I'll have to worry about those!" - that's good, since you can't parse nested structures with (.NET) regular expressions :)

Comment: @Porges, you can perfectly parse those using [balancing groups](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups).

Comment: @Lucero: Wow, thanks! I've looked for something to match Perls' recursive expressions for a while, and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Porges, I tried them out and they do work really well. But my preference is still to use a proper parser for anything more complex (I wrote [an engine](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-goldparser/) for the [GOLD Parser](http://www.devincook.com) which I use for any [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) parsing needs).

Comment: Nice. I've never heard of balancing groups - they look very powerful. Love it when I come on here to ask a simple question, and end up learning a bunch of new things at the same time!

Comment: I've got something up my sleeves :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the greedy quantifier for the `value` group. Use this:

```
\{\{if\:(?<condition>[^\}]+)\}\}(?<value>.+?)\{\{endif\}\}
```

Comment: I'd make two small tweaks: allow single `}`s in the 'condition', and allow 'value' to be empty: `{{if:(?<condition>(?:(?!}}).)*)}}(?<value>.*?){{endif}}`.

Comment: I thought about the exact same suggestions (plus one regarding the [`RegexOptions.SingleLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)), but then decided against it in order to specifically address the lazy/greedy matching issue here.